# Vertically centering images, within a row, with rows created by clearing floats every 4n+1 elements

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, html

I have a question around vertically centering images which I haven't been able to find a solution to and would love to tap some other folks' brains. I am working on this page: http://www.heirloomtileworks.com/newsite/gift-tiles

The usual solutions haven't been working so far (at least not the way I've implemented them). My images are *not* contained within a div on a per-row basis; rather the rows of images are created by clearing floats every 4n+1 child elements.

The images may be a variety of heights, and the div is also not of fixed height. Images are added via the content manager. Each image is contained within div styled in this way:

```
#gift-tile-small-container {
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

These divs containing images currently flow down the page within a div (#gift-tile-container). So each row is created not by a separate div, but like so:

```
div#gift-tile-container div:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

I would like each `#gift-tile-small-container` div to align with the others in its row, so that the vertical centerpoint of each div is aligned with that of it's rowmates.

If you need to see the HTML as well, let me know, although it is written in Textpattern native tags and not normal HTML. It should be fairly self-explanatory. I appreciate your help!

Comment: As an alternative solution, you could always use CSS columns.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: ID should be unique, if you need to apply the same styles to multiple elements then use class instead of id

Comment: @Huangism IDs **MUST** be unique ;).

Comment: Fixed, it is now a class, not an ID. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. Use inline block for the containers. I reduced the right margin because between each div container, there is white space. I tried this in firebug and it seems to work

```
#gift-tile-small-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Again, as I mentioned in the comments, if you need to apply the same style to multiple elements. Use class instead of ID.